# C++ WinSock 2 - socket crashing when getpeername() function is used

Tags: c++, sockets, websocket, crash, winsock2

Whenever I use the function `getpeername()`, my program crashes and returns 255 when debugging. It `printf`'s the hostname, and when it starts to try to `printf` the peername, it says "Peer Name: " and then crashes before it tells me the peername. I know this program doesn't have much of a point to it. I'm just messing with some WinSock 2 functions to see what all of them do.

My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define SCK_VERSION2 0x0202
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT 27015

int main() {
    //----------------------
    // Declare and initialize variables.
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in clientService;

    char name[500] = "";

    sockaddr sName;
    int sNameSize =  sizeof(sName);

    char *sendbuf = "Test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
      printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
      return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %i\n", WSAGetLastError() );
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );
    clientService.sin_port = htons(444);

    //----------------------
    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) );
    if ( iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket (ConnectSocket);
        printf("Unable to connect to server: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    //Get local host name
    iResult = gethostname(name, sizeof(name));
    if (iResult == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("Host Name: %s\n", name);
    }
    else if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Could not resolve host name: %i", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    iResult = getpeername(ConnectSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&sName, &sNameSize);
    if (iResult == NO_ERROR)
        printf("Peer Name: %s", sName);
    else if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("Could not get peer name: %i", WSAGetLastError());

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %i\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 )
            printf("Bytes received: %s\n", recvbuf); //printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while( iResult > 0 );

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you expect this to do? `printf("Peer Name: %s", sName);`?  The code you have declares `sName` as a sockaddr, not a null-terminated C-string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
struct sockaddr_in  sockaddr;
int namelen = sizeof(sockaddr);
if(!getpeername( socket, (struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr, &namelen))
{
   printf("Peer Name: %s\n", inet_ntoa((in_addr)(* (in_addr*)&sockaddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your call.

1. your socket is an IPv4 socket, so `getpeername()` expects a `sockaddr_in`, just like `connect()` does.  But you have declared your `sName` variable as `sockaddr` instead.  you need to use the correct structure type for the socket type:

   ```
   sockaddr_in sName;
   ```
2. you are trying to print out `sName` as if it were a null-terminated string, but it is not.  It is a binary structure.  You have to convert its content into a null-terminated string, such as with `inet_ntoa()`:

   ```
   iResult = getpeername(ConnectSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&sName, &sNameSize);
   if (iResult == 0)
       printf("Peer Name: %s", inet_ntoa(sName.sin_addr));
   else
       printf("Could not get peer name: %i", WSAGetLastError());
   ```

Comment: Is peer name supposed to be a bunch of numbers?

Comment: @EdwardSeverinsen: Yes. `getpeername()` returns the peer's IP address. You do understand what an IP address actually is, right? A set of numbers indicating a device's address within a network. What you are trying to do is print out a *human readable* representation of that IP address, which is why you cannot print out the content of the `sockaddr_in` structure directly, but instead have to convert it to a printable format first.

Comment: Nvm I forgot to replace `%d` with `%s` XD